# Webfont from fonts.com are appearing too thick

Tags: css, macos, fonts, webkit, webfonts

I'm having a problem with fonts.com fonts ( Avenir in particular ). I've tried to ask them about this problem, but they couldn't reproduce it.

These two images are of the same text with the same CSS, except different sites:

**Fonts.com:**

[image: Fonts.com render]

**My site:**

[image: My site's render]

This is on Chrome on a Mac. Firefox isn't as bad, but still a bit thicker. I haven't tested it in IE yet, but I don't think it'll have the same problem.

So what's causing this? Why is behaving differently *in the same browser/OS*?

Comment: If Fonts.com cannot reproduce the problem, what can we do, with *much* less information? There’s no code, to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, it could be a lot of things, can you post the code where these examples came from. Or you could just lower the font-weight on your site to make it look like fonts.com

Comment: TBH, code wouldn't have helped, the declaration that was needed didn't appear in the inspector.

Comment: fonts.com applies -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased to the html element, so it hits the whole page.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now, but I thought the inspector included relevant styles of containing elements on each element. I was wrong.

Comment: By default the inspector will only show styles that are applied directly to that element.  If you choose "computed styles", you can see inherited styles, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Subpixel antialiasing on OSX can make fonts look quite bold.  That seems to be the issue here.

Look at this blown up shot of the text that you posted:

[image]

See that color fringing around your text?  That's subpixel antialiasing.

What you can do is turn it off using CSS:

```
.yourtext {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

As you can probably tell from the -webkit vendor prefix, this will only work for Safari and Chrome.  There are hack-ish methods of disabling sub pixel antialiasing in Firefox for OSX (like `opacity: .99`) but I don't know if they're a good idea.

I'm a little surprised that Fonts.com isn't aware of this, especially since they are disabling sub pixel antialiasing themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have saved me a lot of trouble friend.

Comment: In addition to `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` some may find the type also improves with `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` and `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you've set up font antialiasing as Chris Herbert explained, but the problem persists, make sure that when declaring a font with `@font-face...`, you have set a value to `font-weight` instead of `font-weight: normal;`. `font-weight: 600;` seems to work best in my case while all other result in the same faux-bold type.